# How to call the GCC compiler from a Ruby on Rails Web Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, gcc, shell-exec

I have one text area where the user types in a basic C program such as printing Hello World or addition of two numbers.
Now, I want the user to be able to click on a button so that whatever code he types gets compiled and its output is shown onto another text area.

I am a beginner to rails and don't know how to implement this. A link to any tutorial for the same will be appreciated. I tried searching on google but was unable to find a suitable solution.

I am looking for something similar to shell_exec for PHP.
For example, in PHP

```
<?php
shell_exec('gcc myfile.c -o a');
shell_exec('./a');
?>
```

Comment: This is a serious security risk.

Comment: I understand but I am trying to go one step at a time. I intend to work on the security aspect at a later stage. I'm learning rails and have decided to take this up as a personal project so in any case I won't be actually deploying anywhere else other than my own PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this in ruby:

1, Backticks

```
`gcc myfile.c -o a`
`./a`
```

2, [system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system)

```
system("gcc myfile.c -o a")  
system("./a")
```

3, [IO#popen](See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-popen)

```
IO.popen("gcc myfile.c -o a")
IO.popen("("gcc myfile.c -o a")
```

N.B: There are more ways to do this (IO:popen3, exec...)

Answer (score 0):

There is a great Ruby Quicktips article on that topic: [Execute shell commands](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands).